# Chat Room ID feature request

Tags: feature-request

It’s hard to locate a chat room by topic (question or answer) by chat-room title, as the title area is taken up by introductory material.

Could the intro be shortened to show some content?

I searched “chat room” and didn’t find anything relevant.

Comment: If you go to the main chat page (https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=english.stackexchange.com) and type "wish" in the "filter rooms" box with the "active" tab selected, it should get you the chat rooms you're looking for. Does that work for you?

Comment: Not really, as that was not the point.  I’ll edit the question to delete the example.  One should not, I think, need a keyword in mind to see what’s been moved to chat.

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly, you would like for the name of the chat rooms where comments have been moved to be changed from something like:

> Discussion on answer by aesking: How did “to wish that” come to hate the present tense in the subordinate clauses it governs, and why is it alone in this?

to something like:

> How did “to wish that” come to hate the present tense in the subordinate clauses it governs, and why is it alone in this? Discussion on answer by aesking

The simplest solution to make the titles "browseable" would be to ask the mod team to get in the habit of renaming the chat room to move the "Discussion on..." text to the end of the name.

That said, if you just want to find all of the chat rooms for a question and its answers, you can put the question ID in the "filter" box. The process of moving the comments to chat puts the question URL in the description of the chat room.

Comment: After the English Lanuage &U chat room, here's what shows up: Discussion on answer...Imported from a comment discussion on https://english.stackexchange.co...(next box) Discussion between a...Imported from a comment discussion on https://english.stackexchange.co...[etc. etc. etc.]  You can look at the chat page to see what I mean.  Unfortunately I can take a screen shot but don't know how to put it into a comment.

Comment: Also I do not wish to ask the mod team to do additional routine tasks.  I was assuming that the headings in the chat-room boxes are pre-programmed and could be modified.

Comment: If you have screenshots, you might want to edit them into your answer. Changing the automatic title for the chat room would probably be a site-wide feature, and you might want to request it on the main meta  ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/ ). I did a quick search there and there were no similar recent feature requests.

Comment: I have discovered that the entire title of a chat room shows up if one hovers over it with a mouse or, on ipad, presses on the title.  So this is good enough; except for specifically created chat rooms, every forum on the site deals with comments moved to chat the same way, so the code is site-wide.  Thanks for your help, @ColleenV